# Partially updating the component when I am updating it every 6 seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that displays some status (I fetch it using a GET endpoint and storing it in a state called `statusRows`.)

```
export const Status = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [statusRows, setStatusRows] = useState([])
    const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('submitted_on') // or 'run' or 'success'
    const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState('desc') // or asc
```

I have the states as above.

The function that I use the fetch the status from an API is as follows

```
const getInstallStatus = () => {
        let options = {
            headers: header,
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
        }
        const urls = [GET_ENDPOINT];
        const fetchJson = url => fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json());
        Promise.all(urls.map(fetchJson))
            .then(([status]) => {
                setStatusRows(status)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
        const rows = [];
        rows.forEach((item) => {
            rows.push(createTableData(item.profile, ... // hidden))
        })
        setStatusRows(rows)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getInstallStatus()
    }, []);
```

As you can see, I reformat the response to a table data and store into the `statusRows`. I use this state to render these data in a table format.

This gets rendered once when the component is loaded since it's using useEffect with `[]`.

I also have another `useEffect` with intervals to update this every 6 seconds.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        // setSec(sec => sec + 1);
        let options = {
            headers: header,
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
        }
        const urls = [GET_ENDPOINT];
        const fetchJson = url => fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json());
        Promise.all(urls.map(fetchJson))
            .then(([status]) => {
                let sortedArr = status
                sortedArr.sort(function (a, b) {
                    var keyA = new Date(a.submitted_on),
                        keyB = new Date(b.submitted_on);
                    // Compare the 2 dates
                    if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
                    if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
                    return 0;
                });
                setStatusRows(sortedArr)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
        const rows = [];
        statusRows.forEach((item) => {
            rows.push(createTableData(item....))
        })
        setStatusRows(rows)
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

So, this technically re-calls the GET endpoint every 6 seconds to show the up-to-date result of the status. However, whenever it gets refreshed, the table goes empty for a second since the table data is in the process of getting re-filled.

Is there a way to make the update smoother? I don't want to make the state empty during the update. I just want to make it update it smoothly. `e.g. Current [Old] --> [] --> [New], Intended: [Old] --> [New]`

Any help, please?

**Edit**

```
const createTableData = (profile, run_on_devices, submitted, testcase, status, success_status, jenkins_log_url) => {
    return { profile, run_on_devices, submitted, testcase, status, success_status, jenkins_log_url };
}
```

Comment: What's the deal with your code that starts with `rows` ? You make an empty array then immediately `forEach` over it which won't do anything since its empty, and then set status rows to be that empty array. what's that code?

Comment: I create an empty `row` array and just go over the array of objects and turn that into a data that is renderable as a table row format then push that int the `row` array so that I can render the table.

Comment: that's not what the code you posted does. the code makes and empty array and you loop over that empty array so it never calls your forEach callback and you setStatusRows to be am empty array. that's exactly why your tabls shows nothing for a bit until your promise resolves. just remove that code and everything should work

Comment: @azium sorry for the confusion. I updated the code (the 2nd one which is pretty much the same as the first one). I modified in a weird way when I was posting to hide some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you're using a Promise.all which executes asynchronously, then right after that block you're setting the state to an empty array which would clear your data. I believe you can simply set the state in the .then and everything would be happy.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        // setSec(sec => sec + 1);
        let options = {
            headers: header,
            method: 'get',
            mode: 'cors',
        }
        const urls = [GET_ENDPOINT];
        const fetchJson = url => fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json());
        Promise.all(urls.map(fetchJson))
            .then(([status]) => {
                let sortedArr = status
                sortedArr.sort(function (a, b) {
                    var keyA = new Date(a.submitted_on),
                        keyB = new Date(b.submitted_on);
                    // Compare the 2 dates
                    if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
                    if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
                    return 0;
                });
                const temp = sortedArr.map(createTableData)
                setStatusRows(temp)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            });
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get your answer. Are you saying put the `createTableData` inside `.then`?

Comment: I dont think I've used that design pattern, normally you would map over your data inside of the return of the component, I'm assuming createTableData is a function you've written? What does it return? Can you post that function as well?

Comment: It's just a formatter for rendering the Material-UI table. I added the code

Comment: Yes I think you just need to change `setStatusRows(sortedArr)` to `setStatusRows(sortedArr.map(createTableData))`

Comment: I think @azium nailed it on the head, definitely better practice though to map over the array onto another variable then pass that variable into state

Comment: @bryanstevens314 do you mean instead of inlining it? makes no difference

Comment: I did `setStatusRows(sortedArr.map(createTableData))` and it gives me `TypeError: func.apply is not a function`

Comment: do `const temp = sortedArr.map(item => createTableData(item.... ))` the way you have it in your question

Comment: Yes and no, inline will work but everything doesn't have to be a fancy one liner, there are times it's more performant to break things up a bit

Comment: There is 100% no way it affects performance. I would argue that breaking it up is good for readability and only that.. which is still worth it, but knowing the difference between readability and correctness is important as well and they are both equally correct in function and performance

Comment: @Dawn17 your `createTableData` function isn't doing anything.. just taking args and putting them into an object.. unless you've left stuff out